# How can I center a table relative to one column in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, centering

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of this:

```
        Center
          |
+----+---------+
|    |    |    |
+----+---------+
     +---------+----+
     |    |    |    |
     +---------+----+
```

Basically, I'm trying to build a table for which some of the items will have prefixes (like a currency symbol) and others will have suffixes. However, I want the cells containing the main data itself to be what is aligned relative to the center, and what comes before or after it to "hang" on the sides. Is what I'm describing possible, and perhaps more importantly, is there a good way to do this cross-browser?

Here is an example of what I'm referring to:
http://jsfiddle.net/akjs80fs/

In the fiddle I linked, if it were formatted as I'm trying to achieve, the "X" would be in the center of the page.

Comment: It is hard to help when you don't have a sample code/markup that we can see what do you want to achieve, and what data you are working with. Can you post an example on JSFiddle perhaps?

Comment: What about when number doesn't fill entire center cell? Will you leave prefix or suffix hand with trailing or leading blank spaces?

Comment: Why can't you just have a 3-column table and use CSS it hide the prefix and suffix cells if there's no data in them?

Comment: @Brett's way is the only way to properly accomplish what you're trying to do using tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use blank columns:

Built it like you mentioned, but instead leave the 2 areas with an `x` blank, and remove the outside borders of these areas.

```
        Center
          |
+----+---------+----+
|    |    |    | x  |
+----+---------+----+
+----+---------+----+
| x  |    |    |    |
+----+---------+----+
```

You can center the entire table on the page, or keep it justified to the left. It does not matter since the table will auto align. Make it a super simple table, like this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="noborder">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noborder">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

add css accordingly:

```
table td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.noborder {
    border:0px;
}
```

Made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ap4jnmtz/) for the funs

Comment: Thanks! What was the answer I was looking for!